# Proof convexity of Logarithmic function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**Prove** that: $\ln(e^{x+y} +1 )$

is a convex function.

I have tried to used $F \circ G$, while

$F = \ln (t+1)$ and $G = e^{x+y}$

$G$ is convex but I need to prove that $F$ is convex and growing, which I do not get. Thank you for any kind of help or hints.

Comment: $f(t)$ is twice differentiable for $t > 0$, so you could check the appropriate criterion, but I am afraid it is concave, rather than convex.

Comment: Exactly that is what I get, but according to my solution it states that the ln function is convex, do not state how though.

Comment: $F$ is concave, but that doesn't mean $F\circ G$ can't be convex. If we look at $h(x) = \ln (ce^x+1)$, we find that $h$ is convex by computing $h''(x)$. Similarly here, compute the Hesse matrix and see whether it's positive (semi)definite.

Comment: Okey, so we set $c = e^{y}$ ? I got it! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=\log(e^{x+y}+1)$.  Then, we have

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{e^{x+y}}{e^{x+y}+1}=1-\frac{1}{e^{x+y}+1}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{e^{x+y}}{(e^{x+y}+1)^2}>0$$

Therefore, since the non-mixed second partial derivatives are positive (we only need non-negative) and the determinant of the Hessian is zero (again, we only need it to be non-negative), then we conclude that  $f$ is convex.